# Express a percentage as a range value

Tags: excel

I have a range:

1.75 [which I need to be 100%] to 4 [which needs to be 0%] (inclusive).

**I need to be able to put in the percent, and get back the value.**

How would I find the value for a percentage, say 50%, using a formula in Excel?

**What I have tried so far:** If I 'pretend' to reverse the percentage so that 1.75 is 0% and 4 is 100%, it seems a lot easier: I can use = (x - 1.75) / (4 - 1.75) * 100 to return the percentage of x, which is to say (x - min) / (max - min) * 100 = percentage of a range.

But I can't get this to work when the max is actually lower than the min. And...I'm not looking for the percent, I'm looking for the value when I enter the percent. :-/

Comment: Why on earth has this been voted down? Have I not asked a legit question?

Comment: @pnuts agreed, but sometimes programming boils down to math[s]

Comment: @andy ye think? I will be very careful about what and 'where' I ask things from now on.

Comment: Ok... no harm done. :)

Comment: I agree with what @pnuts said. I also regard what gets asked here with substantial latitude in terms of "relevance", though I might be a heretic for that. While I appreciate the SE vision, I don't think it always makes sense. That said, SE is an evolving creature, and I think that's really good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percentage of the `value` in the range is

```
=(max - value) / (max - min)
```

The value at some `percentage` is

```
=(min - max) * percentage + max
```

Edit: Perhaps a more intuitive way to attack "the value at some `percentage`" (notice I changed the terms here):

```
= (max - min) * (1- percentage) + min
```

IOW,

```
= (total distance) * (complement of fractional distance) + baseline
```

The `complement` is needed because you have reversed the sense of upper and lower bounds.

Comment: Many thanks! This works. Very thorough and a great explanation for my feeble mind.

Comment: @pnuts This is a good analogy, but I would steer clear of examples of 50%, since the right answer might be come out of the wrong formula. 50% from either end gets you to the right place, but you might be starting from the wrong end, if you get my meaning. A more rigorous example in my view is to test something off-center and near (but not necessarily at) borderlines. No wait, borderline cases need to be tested too (^:

Comment: I see the importance of the "complement of fractional distance" now, thanks for explaining that little nugget - I would never have figured that out in a month of Sundays.

Comment: @Andy when you added (1-perc) + min, should that not be + max? Max works in my formula, where min does not. Perc is between 0 (0%) and 1 (100%). Maybe I'm just missing something? YEP I MISSED SOMETHING...no worries.

Comment: Make sure you followed how I switched the `min` and `max` terms between the original post and the Edit. You should be able to enter 0% or 100% (any % really) and get the same result either way.

Comment: @Andy, (I had to change the first 2 terms too). How you fathom this out in your head is beyond me completely. Really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

Like so, I used `=4-(2.25*A1)`,`=4-(2.25*A2)` and `=4-(2.25*A3)`

```
0       4
0.5     2.875
1       1.75
```